# iOS icon goes black after installing from iTunes

Tags: ios, iphone, phonegap-build

I'm trying to write my own **iOS** app using **PhoneGap**. So far, the app works fine on my Android version. However, when trying to install on *iOS*, the icon shows up on the phone, then goes to 100% - but when it gets to 100%, the icon goes black!

Here is what I see when its doing the install:

[image]

..then it goes all black once it gets to 100%:

[image]

This is with a production p12 / mobileprovision file (not development).

The annoying thing is that the development one works fine! I've done a lot of reading up - but I'm not totally sure how the process of making the live app works. Does it need verification from Apple, before it will fully load on my test device?

Apple *really* need to sort out the whole certification system. Far too complex! I've literally spent 3 1/2 days on this so far, just to create the damn certificates!

UPDATE: Ok, so I've tried re-creating my profiles / certificates, and still no joy :( Here is how I'm going about it. Can anyone see somewhere I could be going wrong?

1. *Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Request a Certificate From a Certificate Authority.* - then enter my email (same as my developer accounts address), and a name. Set as "**Save to Disk**"
2. Now I have the .certSigningRequest file
3. Go into "Certificates", and create a new one (**App Store and Ad Hoc**) - uploading the file from the last step. I then download the *.cer* file that it outputs from this process
4. Double click the new *.cer* file, and let it import into my **KeyChain**. I can see the new certificate fine in "Certificates", as well as the user in "Keys"
5. Expand the "Keys" section, I find the new certificate - expand it (so I can see the Private Key AND Certificate), then highlight both. Right click, and choose "Export 2  items". This then gives me the p12 file
6. Then back in the Apple Developer panel, I go to Provisioning Profiles > Distribution, and add a new one based on the "iOS Distribution" certificate I have)
7. Download the *.mobileprovision* file it outputs.
8. Then, I put the p12 and .mobileprovision file into PhoneGap Build, and try a build.
9. After its compiled, I then try and install it on my device - which comes up with the "waiting" issue on the icon

**UPDATE 2:** I managed to get it going by doing an "Ad Hoc" provisioning file, not "Store" one.

Comment: Does application successfully open?

Comment: @Kampai Nope - its as if its still trying to install. If I tap it, I get "**Waiting...**" come up. If I look at it in iTunes, it says "**Remove**" alongside the app. Its almost like it didn't finish installing - but I don't get any error messages. FWIW, I've tried removing the app and re-installing afresh - but still no joy

Comment: It means your app is not provisioned to install on particular device.

Comment: Aah, the problem isn't with the app icon, as you commented, its in state of `Waiting`. You should look for how to remove app which are installing (in waiting state) and reinstalling the app.

Comment: Hemang - is is a problem with the icon (it shows black). CoolMonster- I've checked my UDID settings, and the device its installing on DOES exist in my "**Devices > All**" , so not sure thats it :/

Comment: Try to configure all the provision files properly and then rebuild the app. I am sure its related to provision problem.

Comment: @CoolMonster - ok, giving it a go. Driving me nuts how complicated it is to make these files! May have to clean it all out, and re-start it all from scratch again. I'm amazed anyone bothers developing on Apple ATM - they need to sort out the system instead of killing developers trying to creates apps :(

Comment: @CoolMonster - I've updated the above post with details on how I'm generating the files. Can you spot anything I'm doing wrong? It still doesn't wanna install :(

Answer (score -1):

Issue is:

UDID of device in which you have install this application is not included in provisional profile.

You must have to add this device in device list of this application- Create new provisional profile again and then create new archive with new provisional profile.

**[App Distribution Guideline](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH30-SW1)** will help you.

One more thing to notice here is: In ***newer Xcode*** if you install same provisional profile more than one time, it will not remove old one but it creates new one and when you create archive you can see all provisional profiles old and new in a list.

Generally everyone select first most provisional profile from list.

**So need to take care is from that multiple list of provisional profile list please select last one.**

***Because every time you install provisional profile the latest provisional profile is placed at last of that profile list.***

*This issue can not be easily observed. And I was stuck for days to solve this.*

Comment: Thanks. I've already done this though. I can see the 2 test devices in "**Devices > All**". The certificate I created was for "**App Store and Ad Hoc**" , and then followed the instructions on how to create the p12/mobileprovision files. The annoying thing, is that it installs and runs fine as a "Developer" app if I create the certificates the same way

Comment: @AndrewNewby: Check one more thing i have added in answer.

Comment: Mmm you could be right. The provisioning profile is coming up as "Invalid"... but it doesn't give me any clues as to why its not valid?

Comment: When you go for creating archive, take a try select last provisional profile and install again in device. Lets see it's work or not?

Comment: Ok giving it another go. So complicated to do though, as I'm trying to do it on a small mac laptop (I'm a Windows7 man myself - can't stand macs!), which means it takes much longer to do than I would like

Comment: I do understand the complexity of this procedure take care on each turn.

Comment: - I've updated the above post with details on how I'm generating the files. Can you spot anything I'm doing wrong? It still doesn't wanna install :(

Comment: got it! I created an Ad Hoc certificate instead, and this now installs! Whats the process for the "App Store" certificate... is that just so you can create a certificate for compiling, before it gets sent to Apple for submission to the store? (bit crap if you can't install it to verify it installs ok!!!!)

Comment: You have to save it for Enterprise. See this - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH33-SW1

Comment: Ah ok. But if you are releasing it for store approval, you just do the same process as ad-hoc, and then submit that file? (but with "Store" not "Ad Hoc" selected) ... ya? Bit hard to verify you got it right, if they wont let you test install it on your device :/